# unable to get query string value after URL rewriting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, request.querystring

I have this rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pages.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

URL structure is like website/pages/about-us

where about-us is the alias of page.

at pages.php i am trying to get the value of alias via `$_GET["alias"]` or `$_REQUEST["alias"]` but no value is retrieving.

Comment: You need at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your server config to be able to use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`

Comment: I think its enabled as its going to pages.php but not reading the querystring.